# How to read multiple JSONs from single JSON file and use in request body

Tags: jmeter

During API Testing, I am aware of the fact that if I need to have different request body values being used by different users/threads, I have to provide a CSV with same variables, use CSV Data Set Config sampler, name the variables and then use these variables in HTTP Request sampler Body Data.

My question is, can the same thing be somehow achieved by a single JSON file? Lets say JSON file will have multiple request bodies which will be read and picked up by different users/threads. Basically, replace the CSV file with a JSON file somehow. Is this possible?

CSV file content:

```
album, year, US_peak_chart_post
The White Stripes, 1999, -
De Stijl, 2000, -
White Blood Cells, 2001, 61
```

JSON file content:

```
[
  {
    "album": "The White Stripes",
    "year": 1999,
    "US_peak_chart_post": "-"
  },
  {
    "album": "De Stijl",
    "year": 2000,
    "US_peak_chart_post": "-"
  },
  {
    "album": "White Blood Cells",
    "year": 2001,
    "US_peak_chart_post": 61
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you put the JSON payload in one line

line instead of this:

```
[
  {
    "album": "The White Stripes",
    "year": 1999,
    "US_peak_chart_post": "-"
  },
  {
    "album": "De Stijl",
    "year": 2000,
    "US_peak_chart_post": "-"
  },
  {
    "album": "White Blood Cells",
    "year": 2001,
    "US_peak_chart_post": 61
  }
]
```

you use this:

```
[{"album":"The White Stripes","year":1999,"US_peak_chart_post":"-"},{"album":"De Stijl","year":2000,"US_peak_chart_post":"-"},{"album":"White Blood Cells","year":2001,"US_peak_chart_post":61}]
```

Example service: https://www.browserling.com/tools/remove-all-whitespace

and choose other delimiter than comma it should work just fine with the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function.

Also be aware that you can build JSON request body from the CSV file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), see [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) article for more information.